# edittext cursor remains at starting position

Tags: android, android-edittext, cursor

I have 3 editText fields of the type Number(Decimal). Two of which have onTextChanged listeners supposed to carry out mathematical functions when any integer is entered. My problem is the edittext fields with the listeners have the cursors stuck on the starting position i.e if i try to type 25, it ends up being 52.

CODE:

```
package com.example.Prototype;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class productsFragmentTab extends Fragment {

Button newProduct, clear;
Spinner productList;
EditText quantity, unit, total;
String invoice_id;
ShowAlert alert = new ShowAlert();
int unitcost, totalcost;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_layout, container, false);

    newProduct = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button4);
    clear = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button5);

    productList = (Spinner)rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    quantity = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText5);
    unit = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText7);
    total = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText8);

    invoice_id = GlobalApp.data().id;



    newProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Save current records in array
            //Clear all textboxes



        }
    });

    clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //clear all textboxes


        }
    });

    unit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        boolean isChangingByCode = false;

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (isChangingByCode) {
                return;
            }
            String qty = quantity.getText().toString();
            if (qty.matches("")) {


            } else {

                    totalcost = Integer.parseInt(qty) * Integer.parseInt(unit.getText().toString());
                    isChangingByCode = true;
                    total.setText(Integer.toString(totalcost));
                    isChangingByCode = false;

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

    total.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        boolean isChangingByCode = false;

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (isChangingByCode) {
                return;
            }
            String qty = quantity.getText().toString();
            if (qty.matches("")) {


            } else {

                    unitcost = Integer.parseInt(total.getText().toString()) / Integer.parseInt(qty);
                    isChangingByCode = true;
                    unit.setText(Integer.toString(unitcost));
                    isChangingByCode = false;

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use setSelection() method to set cursor position at last.
Add following code:

```
total.setText(Integer.toString(totalcost));
total.setSelection(total.getText().length());
```

in place of `total.setText(Integer.toString(totalcost));` in onTextChanged() callback.

```
 @Override 
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if (isChangingByCode) {
            return; 
        } 
        String qty = quantity.getText().toString();
        if (qty.matches("")) {


        } else { 

                totalcost = Integer.parseInt(qty) * Integer.parseInt(unit.getText().toString());
                isChangingByCode = true;
                total.setText(Integer.toString(totalcost));
                total.setSelection(total.getText().length());
                isChangingByCode = false;

        } 

    }
```